# Mobile Chrome 66 can't autoplay muted ?

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video, autoplay

It seems like chrome on mobile has completely blocked autoplay on a specific version (66).
The videos were autoplaying in previous versions and are working on newer versions (67).

Test:

```
<video controls autoplay muted src="pathToFile.mp4"></video>
```

FiddleJS - https://jsfiddle.net/josewirewax/u4128v7s/

Tests results:

- **Video doesn't autoplay on mobiles with Chrome/66.0.3359.158**
  OnePlus 3 - Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; Build/OPR1.170623.032) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.158 Mobile Safari/537.36
- **It autoplays on mobiles with Chrome/67.0.3396.68** 
  Pixel - Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.1.0; Pixel Build/OPM4.171019.016.B1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.68 Mobile Safari/537.36
- Wasn't able to test with older versions

I can't trigger play() without user interaction, otherwise I get the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.
```

Am I missing something in the code ? Is any documentation or blog post from chrome talking about this ? is there any workaround ?

Answer (score 1):

I have run into the same problem and it was caused by the **data saver** being allowed on the mobile device, which has completely prevented autoplay.

Upon switching off the data saver the autoplay setting went into allowed state and the videos started autoplaying.

I haven't found a way to reliably autoplay videos on devices with data saver enabled, the user needs to interact with the document and then the `.play()` function needs to be called.